# select matching objects from array in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

```
{
    class: 1,
    users: [{
        name: 'abc',
        surname: 'def'
    }, {
        name: 'xyz',
        surname: 'wef'
    }, {
        name: 'abc',
        surname: 'pqr'
    }]
}
```

I have a document structure like above object and I want to return only users who have name 'abc' but problem is it matches name 'abc' but returns 
all array. I want only matched users .

Mapping -

```
{
        "class":"string",
        "users" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties": {
                "name" : {"type": "string" },
                "surname"  : {"type": "string" }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your query? and possibly also your mapping?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Then if you have your `users` field mapped as `nested` type, it's a good start!

Using [nested `inner_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html#nested-inner-hits), you can retrieve only the matching user names with a query like this one:

```
{
  "_source": false,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "users",
      "inner_hits": {        <---- this is where the magic happens
        "_source": [
          "name"
        ]
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "users.name": "abc"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can we do "_source": false for specific _type ?

Comment: You can definitely narrow your search query to a specify type by specifying the type directly in the URL `/my_index/my_type/_search` if that's what you mean.

Comment: Can we get all normal fields with only matching nested fields ?
like
{
    class: 1,
    users: [{
        name: 'abc',
        surname: 'def'
    }]
}

Comment: @JayShah If you set `_source: true` it should get you what you want

Comment: Yes, but if I set _source: true, It gives me all nested objects. I need only matching nested objects.
like
{
    class: 1,
    users: [{
        name: 'abc',
        surname: 'def'
    }]
}
Is that possible ?

Comment: Ah I see, you want the matching nested objects but at the top level. Then no.

Comment: OK, Is there any other work around by which in source, we don't get nested objects and we can get matching nested objects as inner hits ?

Comment: You might want to create a brand new question for this (and reference this one) as this might interest other people, too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128825/discussion-between-jay-shah-and-val).