# Make Elastic Search return certain items from a list

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, search, aws-elasticsearch

I have list of complex object *(address in below example)* where each object has attributes as {string,string,string,string,string}.

I want to do filtering on the list and instead of entire document, I just want to get 2 items from the list in the response. Is it possible?

e.g.
Customer:{
id,
address-list:{
street,
city,
postal,
state,
country
}
}

If we have 5 addresses and we want to apply filter on the city value of the address object, is it possible in elastic search?

I know we have include and exclude using which we can filter on the attribute but can we also filter based on attribute value? Instead of getting all the 5 addresses present in a document, can we pull all the attributes but for addresses, we pull items having city="Chicago" in the output of elastic? 
**Nested Mapping looks like:**

```
{
"mappings": { 
"employee": 
{ 
"properties": 
{ 
"addrBean": { "type": "nested", 
"properties": { 
"addrId": { "type": "integer" }, 
"city": { "type": "string" }, 
"state": { "type": "string" }, 
"country": { "type": "string" } 
} } } } 
}
}
```

Comment: Is `address-list` really a list or just an inner object? Stated differently, can a customer have multiple addresses in `address-list` or just a single one?

Comment: A customer can have multiple addresses. We want the customer object in the response but we want to restrict the addresses in the output with a filter. e.g. a customer has 3 addresses with cities Chicago, Moline, Rome; we want to filter the response and get only Chicago in the response from elastic along with the other attributes in customer document.

Comment: Is the `address-list` field of type `nested`?

Comment: What do you mean by type nested? Customer object has address list as attribute. Every address list has address bean (address object) which has 5 string attributes.

Comment: I mean this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html

Comment: Yes that is how it is. I can use address.city to filter out the output documents.

Comment: then this is the answer you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719968/select-matching-objects-from-array-in-elasticsearch/31721025#31721025 (hint: use nested inner_hits)

Comment: Val, this thing has helped me but I have one more list which is not nested. Is there any way for that? Or an alternative question could be how do I make it nested now?

Comment: You need to change your mapping and reindex your data

Comment: I am facing an issue in nested indexing it seems. The columns having integer data are searchable but string values are not. e.g. city : "123" provides results but city : "Moline" doesn't provide result. 0 hits. City is defined as string datatype.

Comment: You need to provide more info, such as your mapping and some sample data to reproduce your issue, otherwise we're shooting in the dark.

Comment: {"mappings": {
    "employee": {
      "properties": {
        "addrBean": {
          "type": "nested",
"properties": {
            "addrId":    { "type": "integer"  },
            "city": { "type": "string"  },
            "state":     { "type": "string"   },
            "country":   { "type": "string"   }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}

Comment: Please update your question with that information, it's more legible

Comment: @Val : Did you get a chance to check this? Have you encountered this issue earlier?

Comment: I found the issue. Elastic matches everything in lower case. When I give all the fields in lowercase, everything works fine.