# Elasticsearch: match only datefields that are None

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm trying to return a list of unit id's where the date field is None.

The example below is just a snippet. A company can have several hundred unit id's, but I only want to return a list of active units (where 'validUntil' is None).

```
'_source': {'company': {'companyId': 1,
                       {'unit': [{'unitId': 1,
                                  'period': {'validUntil': '2016-02-07' }},
                                 {'unitId': 2,
                                  'period': {'validUntil': None }}]

payload = {
    "size": 200,
    "_source": "company.companyId.unitId,
    "query":{
         "term":{
            "company.companyId": "1"
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried several different things (filter, must_not exists etc.), but either the searches return all unit id's pertaining to that company id or nothing, making me suspect that I'm not filtering correctly.

The date format is 'dateOptionalTime' if that is any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your problem might not be in the query itself.
As far as I know, you cannot return only part of the array if it's type is not nested,
I recommend looking at this question:
[select matching objects from array in elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31719968/select-matching-objects-from-array-in-elasticsearch)