# How to select only matching fields of child object in ElasticSearch?

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, kibana, nest

I am facing a problem with searching with Elasticsearch. I am using ES 7.3 for my implementation.

Below is my class structure:

```
    [ElasticsearchType]
    public class InquiryInformation
    {
        [Text(Name = "inquiryNumber")]
        public string InquiryNumber { get; set; }

        [Text(Name = "inquiryStatus")]
        public string InquiryStatus { get; set; }

        [Text(Name = "submitedBy")]
        public string SubmittedBy { get; set; }

        [Nested]
        [PropertyName("files")]
        public List<FileInformation> Files { get; set; }

    }

    [ElasticsearchType]
    public class FileInformation
    {
        [Text(Name = "fileName")]
        public string FileName { get; set; }

        [Text(Name = "fileContent")]
        public string FileContent { get; set; }
    }
```

And used this code to create a mapping:

```
elasticClient.Map<InquiryInformation>(m => m.AutoMap());
```

This has created below index mapping with ES:

```
{
  "city" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "files" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "fileContent" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "fileName" : {
              "type" : "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "inquiryNumber" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "inquiryStatus" : {
          "type" : "text"
        },
        "submitedBy" : {
          "type" : "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, I have to write a query which will search for Users as well as user's files.

Lets say If I search for user with inquiryNumber XYZ1212 then it will return me all the matching records. Now the problem is - I need to return only the matching files. Like if FileName of FileContent contains the matching record information then only matched files should be returned along with document.

I have tried so many ways with NEST. But Failed to get the only matched files. Its always returning me all the files for a specific user.

Any luck for this to achieve my needs ?

> UPDATE 1 Adding Sample Query of C# (NEST)

```
var searchResult = elasticClient.Search<InquiryInformation>(s => s
                    .Query(q => q
                        .MultiMatch(m => m
                            .Fields(f => f
                                .Field("files.fileContent")
                                .Field("files.fileName")
                            )
                            .Query("Hello Stackoverflow")
                        )
                    )
                );
```

> UPDATE 2 : Adding another query:

```
POST city/_search
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [ "*" ],
    "excludes": [ "files" ]
  },
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "files",
      "inner_hits": {
        "_source": [
          "inquiryNumber", "submitedBy"
        ]
      },
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "files.fileContent": "Samsung"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It'd be a good idea to show the query or queries you've tried so far.

Comment: @Val Added Query !

Comment: @Val: I have also checked your comments on https://stackoverflow.com/a/31721025/903507. But no luck for me. Could be be really helpful for me if you can help me to achieve this. I am beginner with ES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `files` field is a `nested` field, you need to leverage a `nested` query as well. Something like this:

```
 var searchResult = elasticClient.Search<InquiryInformation>(s => s
                .Source(false)
                .Query(q => q
                   .Nested(c => c
                      .InnerHits()
                      .Path(p => p.Files)
                      .Query(nq => nq
                        .MultiMatch(m => m
                          .Fields(f => f
                            .Field("files.fileContent")
                            .Field("files.fileName")
                          )
                          .Query("Hello Stackoverflow")
                        )
                      )
                   )
                )
            );
```

Comment: Thankful to you for helping me to generate C# query. Now here the problem is I am getting all the files of specific user. Is there any way to select files with matching keywords only. Files with unmatched keywords will get discarded from search results.

Comment: Don't you have an `InnerHits` section in each hit? that's where the data you're looking for is located. Alternatively, you can also add `.Source(false)` to your query so that only inner hits show up and not the whole document.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Val for your valuable help.

For those who are trying to achieve the same - Below is the C# (NEST) query I used so far:

```
 var searchResult = elasticClient.Search<InquiryInformation>(s => s
               .Query(q => q
                  .Nested(c => c
                     .InnerHits()
                     .Path(p => p.Files)
                     .Query(nq => nq
                       .MultiMatch(m => m
                         .Fields(f => f
                           .Field("files.fileContent")
                           .Field("files.fileName")
                         )
                         .Query("Samsung Galaxy S10")
                       )
                     )
                  )
               )
           );

foreach (var hit in searchResult.Hits)
{
     var file = hit.InnerHits["files"].Documents<FileInformation>();
}
```

> UPDATE 1 - Corrected query with respect to @Val's comment:

```
var searchResult = elasticClient.Search<InquiryInformation>(s => s
               .Query(q => q
                  .Nested(c => c
                     .InnerHits()
                     .Path(p => p.Files)
                     .Query(nq => nq
                       .MultiMatch(m => m
                         .Fields(f => f
                           .Field("files.fileContent")
                           .Field("files.fileName")
                         )
                         .Query("A11117")
                       )
                     )
                  )
               ).Query(q => q
                    .MultiMatch(m => m
                        .Fields(f => f
                            .Field("inquiryNumber"))
                        .Query("A11117")))
           );

            foreach (var hit in searchResult.Hits)
            {
                var file = hit.InnerHits["files"].Documents<FileInformation>();
            }
```

Comment: You cannot add `inquiryNumber` there, because that field is not in the nested `Files` but at the root level of the document, you need another constraint in your query to match on that field.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me ! I have added one more query. I am getting records as per expectations. Requesting you to please correct me if I did anything wrong here also.

Comment: You need to combine both queries into a [bool/must query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/bool-queries.html) otherwise  the second query might override the first one.